# call a javascript function using string name

Tags: javascript

It is a bit complicated for to explain properly what I mean, so please try to understand me :)

I want to be able in javascript to call a element method/function using text sent as parameter. For example:

```
function CallAFunction(function_name){
 document.getElementById('some_id').function_name();
}
```

As you see in the above example, I want to send function_name as parameter, and it is type of string or a simple text. So how I can use this function name to call it like that ?

Or, please suggest me something which may help me get the same as I need.

Comment: document.getElementById('some_id')[function_name](); In JavaScript, x.y is the same as x["y"]

Comment: @RaymondChen you are absolutely right. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use bracket notation;

```
document.getElementById('some_id')[function_name]();
```

Comment: Thank you my friend, you give me a very quick answer, I'm happy, and I will mark this answer as accepted.

Comment: by the way, what will happen if function name not exist for that element ? it will crash the code after it ?

Comment: @JigsweelJigsweel yes it will.  May want to check `elem.hasOwnProperty(function_name)` first and even check if it's callable

Comment: cool, didn't know about that method, and how to check if it's callable ?

Comment: @JigsweelJigsweel no set way, but `typeof(elem[function_name]) === 'function'` should generally work

Comment: how do I do for variable of element, same thing as function ? I tried, but not working: document.getElementById('some_id')[variable_name];

Answer (score 0):

call function name using string :

```
var myFunc = window[myFuncName];
```

you can sent parameter like this :

```
<button onclick="myFunction('Harry Potter','Wizard')">Try it</button>

<script>
function myFunction(name,job)
{
alert("Welcome " + name + ", the " + job);
}
</script>
```